# Show different text when DataGridComboBoxColumn is not in edit mode

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a DataGridComboBoxColumn which is bind to a collection of objects which is type is MyItem. MyItem has two string properties: Description and Shortcut.

If the column is not in edit mode I want to show the string from the Shortcut Property and if the column is in edit mode I want to show the string from the Description property.

Is this possible without a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Further information:
At the moment I've set the DisplayMemberPath property to "Description".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this, I have found, would be to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

`DataGridComboBoxColumn` does not expose either a `CellTemplate` (displayed when not editing) nor a `CellEditingTemplate` (displayed when editing), and instead builds the `ComboBox` templates for you based on the bindings you hand the column. Since you want these to be different, you need a column which exposes both these members, which is `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Simply make the `CellTemplate` a `Label` bound to your `Shortcut` Property, and the `CellEditingTemplate` a `ComboBox` with the same bindings as those you gave your `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

After all that, your column should look something like this

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="...">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Shortcut}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="..."
                        DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                        SelectedItem="..."/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Addendum - The reason I advocate use of `Label` over `TextBlock` here is because `Label` automatically includes alignment and margins. `TextBlock`, lacking these, looks very strange and needs some massaging to get looking right.

Comment: Thanks for the example. My hope was to to it wihtout a DataGridTemplateColumn but I guess it's not possible :/

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could also use a datagridcombobox column, and use a style to override the CellTemplate. This, however, may not work (anything defined inline can't be set with a style setter) and requires about as much tagging as the TemplateColumn solution, so I don't typically recommend it.